# What is the probability that randomly selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification, random

> What is the probability that randomly selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares?  *Note: Every square is also rectangle.*

[image]

- All cases - (contain the upper red square or contain bottom red square)
- contain the upper red square or contain bottom red square
  = $\frac{54}{150} +\frac{48}{150} -\frac{24}{150} =\frac{78}{150}$.
- Then , $1 - \frac{78}{150} =\boxed{\frac{72}{150}}$

However, the given answer is $\boxed{\frac{24}{150}}$ . What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't comprehend your numbers. How did you get them?

Comment: @callculus42 for $54/150$ , i.e.contain upper red square : select $1$ line below , $1$ line above , $1$ line right and $1$ line left : $3*3*3*2 =54$

Comment: OK. Are there additional assumptions for that exercise? I would have calculated $\frac1{20}+\frac1{20}-\frac1{20^2}$ for the probability that randomly selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares.

Comment: @callculus42 so , you found zero ???

Comment: @callculus42 no addition restriction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this boils down to ambiguities in the wording. Your math is correct, but maybe not for the interpretation that the problem setter intended.

1. Probability a rectangle contains *neither* red square, i.e that the number of red squares contained is zero. This is what you correctly calculated:

$$1-\frac{54}{150}-\frac{48}{150}+\frac{24}{150}=\frac{72}{50}$$

2. Probability of *the complement of the event of containing both red squares*. That is, the probability it contains either zero or one red square. This is one minus the probability that the rectangle contains both red squares, so
   $$
   1-\frac{24}{150}=\frac{126}{150}
   $$

I think that both of these situations are possible interpretations of the setup "What is the probability that randomly selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares?". It depends on whether you read this as "it is not true that the rectangle contains both red squares" or "for each red square, the rectangle does not contain it."

However, what is confusing is that $\frac{24}{150}$ fits with neither of these interpretations. Any way I slice it, it seems the book gave the wrong answer, and whether your answer is correct depends on how you interpret the phrasing.

Comment: yes , "will not contain both of the two red squares" mean "the number of red squares contained is zero."

Answer (score 0):

In order for a randomly selected rectangle to include both red squares, two events must both happen.

$E_1$: the event that the lower left corner of the randomly selected rectangle is at or below the lower left corner of the lower red square, and at or to the left of the lower left corner of the lower red square.

Consequently, there are exactly $4$ choices for the lower left corner of the randomly selected rectangle.

$E_2$: the event that the upper right corner of the randomly selected rectangle is at or above the upper right corner of the upper red square, and at or to the right of the upper right corner of the upper red square.

Consequently, there are exactly $6$ choices for the upper right corner of the randomly selected rectangle.

This explains the enumeration of $6 \times 4.$

---

I verified that there are in fact $150$ distinct rectangles that can be formed.  Therefore, the probability that a randomly selected rectangle will contain both red squares is $\displaystyle ~\frac{24}{150}$.

Therefore, the probability that a randomly selected red square will not contain both red squares is

$$1 - \frac{24}{150} = \frac{126}{150}.$$

I suspect that there was a misprint in the problem's wording, either by the OP (i.e. original poster) or by the problem composer.

The alternative is that there is a mistake in my analysis.  If there is one, I can't find it.

Comment: "will NOT contain" :)

Comment: @user0203457689 Thanks for the assist, my carelessness.  Answer edited.

Comment: your answer seems to include the cases where one of them include but the other not

Comment: @user0203457689 How else can you interpret "selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares?".

Comment: if it will not contain both of them , then we should subtract the unwanted cases such that the upper included or the bottom included by P.I.E

Comment: @user0203457689 You are misinterpreting the problem, as it is worded.  the phrase "not contain both of the red squares" is distinct from "not contain either of the red squares".  If exactly one of the red squares is contained, that is a favorable case, that should not be excluded.  My analysis/computation is consistent with this interpretation.  Either the problem composer mis-worded the problem, or you mis-translated the problem.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the problem. What does " do not contain both red squares " mean ? It means that we should count the cases where both reds are included or the upper but not lower or the lower but not upper. Moreover , try to count the rectangles above both of them , there are already $C(5,2)*C(3,2)=30$ rectangles that do not contain both of them

Comment: @user0203457689 I think that we should agree to disagree.  I can only re-state that the phrase "selected rectangles will not contain both of the two red squares" is **distinct** from "selected rectangles will not contain either of the two red squares".  You are reading the 1st phrase as if it is identical to the 2nd phrase, which it is not.

Comment: Lets try to draw a venn diagram such that the universal set is all reactangles in this picture , now draw two circles that represent the subsets such as the possible rectangles contain the above red square and  the possible rectangles contain the below red square. As you see , those circles ,i.e, subsets have intersection. Then , the rest of subset ,i.e universal set - union of these two circle , is our interest.

Comment: @user0203457689 In your Venn diagram, the intersection of the two circles is represented by the $(24)$ rectangles which I enumerated.  What is being asked for is the entire universe, except the **intersection** of the two circles.  What is being asked for is **not** the entire universe except for the **union** of the two circles.  Your previous comment is simply deflecting the issue of the distinction between "**not contain both**" and "**not contain either**".